# Customizing the Bootstrap Brandname component with CSS "animation"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap Navbar I want to replace the text of the Brandname (top left corner) with a CSS "animation". I do not succeed in getting the animation in the topleft corner (it is in the top right corner); and also It dissappears when in large screen, whereas I want to keep it.

This is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/xcywkus2/

[image: navbar small screen]

[image: navbar large screen]

And the html:

```
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-static-top">

    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button"
                 aria-expanded="false"
                 aria-controls="navbar"
                 class="navbar-toggle">

<!--                   <a class="navbar-brand navbar-custom" href="{% url 'home' %}"> -->


                  <a class="navbar-brand navbar-custom">    


                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <div id="our-icon">
                              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </div>
                  </a>
        </button>

        </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button"
                  class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#navbar"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-controls="navbar">

             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <div id="nav-icon4">
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
              </div>

         </button>


        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li><a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Register</a></li>

          </ul>




        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    min-height: 100px;
}

.navbar.navbar-custom {
    margin-bottom: 19px;
    background-color: rgba(204, 78, 63, 0.75);
    border-color: rgba(192, 40, 8, 0.75)
}

/*brandname*/
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 217, 217,1);
    padding: 14x15px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: Raleway;
}

/*The other navbar -not brandname- menu font items*/
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(241,210,210,1);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Raleway;
}

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent !important;
}


.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle  {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}



/* START HAMBURGER bench-toggle */
#nav-icon4 {
  width: 36px;
  height: 14px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1px auto;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon4 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 200, 192, 1);
  border-radius: 9px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}


/* BEFORE collapsed: hamburger */
#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: -4px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 6px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 16px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}


/*The Brandname "animation CSS":*/

#our-icon {
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  /*border-radius: 5px;  */
  position: relative;
}

#our-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px rgba(255, 217, 217,1);
  width: 17.6471%;
  height: 30%;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 0%;
  background: rgba(204, 78, 63, 0.75);
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#our-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#our-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 12%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


#our-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  left: 36%;
  bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-20px,0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(-20px,0px);
  -o-transform: translate(-20px,0px);
  transform: translate(-20px,0px);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .6s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#our-icon span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 3px;
  height: 51%;
  bottom: 27%;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 217,1);
  border: 0;
}

#our-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  width: 3px;
  height: 38%;
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 15.032%;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 217,1);
  border: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg) ;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out .65s;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .6s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#our-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .3s;
}

#our-icon.open span:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 46%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg) ;
  -webkit-transition: .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#our-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  width: 3px;
  height: 40%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 44%;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 217,1);
  border: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .3s;
}

#our-icon.open span:nth-child(6) {
  width: 3px;
  height: 40%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 46.5%;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 217,1);
  border: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-180dreg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg) ;
  -webkit-transition: .35s ease-in-out .35s;
  -moz-transition: .35s ease-in-out .35s;
  -o-transition: .35s ease-in-out .35s;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#our-icon span:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 51%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .6s;
}

#our-icon span:nth-child(6) {
  width: 3px;
  height: 42%;
  bottom: 32%;
  left: 51%;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 217,1);
  border: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .6s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to place it in lieu of the standard `navbar-brand`.

You don't need two seperate `containers` and `navbar-header` divs. Your toggle button and the animation both need to be inside one `navbar-header` div and in the reverse order (`navbar-toggle` then `navbar-brand`).

See working example and [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

***Sidenote:** If your ultimate intention is to use the **animation** to open the mobile menu your have to consider that if you use the same class (which is simple and possible) that the normal toggle button uses, if some clicks on that outside of the mobile viewport (above 768px) you'll have some undesirable results since the menu is all ready exposed, not hidden as the button is intended to work with.

```js
$('#our-icon').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 78, 63, 0.75);
  border-color: rgba(192, 40, 8, 0.75)
}
/*brandname*/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*The other navbar -not brandname- menu font items*/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(241, 210, 210, 1);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Raleway;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
}
/* START HAMBURGER bench-toggle */

#nav-icon4 {
  width: 36px;
  height: 14px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1px auto;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
#nav-icon4 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 200, 192, 1);
  border-radius: 9px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
/* BEFORE collapsed: hamburger */

#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: -4px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 6px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 16px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
/*The Brandname "animation CSS":*/

#our-icon {
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  /*border-radius: 5px;  */
  position: relative;
}
#our-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px rgba(255, 217, 217, 1);
  width: 17.6471%;
  height: 30%;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 0%;
  background: rgba(204, 78, 63, 0.75);
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
#our-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
#our-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 12%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
#our-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  left: 36%;
  bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-20px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(-20px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(-20px, 0px);
  transform: translate(-20px, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .6s;
  opacity: 0;
}
#our-icon span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 3px;
  height: 51%;
  bottom: 27%;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 217, 1);
  border: 0;
}
#our-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  width: 3px;
  height: 38%;
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 15.032%;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 217, 1);
  border: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out .65s;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .6s;
  opacity: 0;
}
#our-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .3s;
}
#our-icon.open span:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 46%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition: .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
#our-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  width: 3px;
  height: 40%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 44%;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 217, 1);
  border: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .3s;
}
#our-icon.open span:nth-child(6) {
  width: 3px;
  height: 40%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 46.5%;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 217, 1);
  border: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-180dreg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition: .35s ease-in-out .35s;
  -moz-transition: .35s ease-in-out .35s;
  -o-transition: .35s ease-in-out .35s;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
#our-icon span:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 51%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .6s;
}
#our-icon span:nth-child(6) {
  width: 3px;
  height: 42%;
  bottom: 32%;
  left: 51%;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 217, 1);
  border: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out .6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

        <div id="nav-icon4"> <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>

        </div>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        <div id="our-icon"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </div>
      </a>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Register</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```